# import happybase works in pyspark shell , but not in spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, pyspark, happybase

I have happybase installed on all nodes of the spark cluster (YARN cluster manager). 
 `import happybase` works from the pyspark shell, and also works when I launch the app using bin/pyspark.
But when I try to launch the app using spark-submit , it throws:

```
 import happybase
ImportError: No module named happybase
```

Comment: Is it installed on all worker nodes? Are you sure your workers use correct Python interpreter?

Comment: yup that was the problem . I needed to set  PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 in spark-env.sh on the master. Thanks a ton !